# How to push the view from left side?

Tags: objective-c

I want to push the view from left side instead of right side.

```
RequestAndLoadViewController *controller=[[RequestAndLoadViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

here we pushing the RequestAndLoadViewController from right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a navigation controller, when you push a view it will always come from the right. If you want to make a view slide in from the left side you need to animate it manually.

See here:

[iPhone Pushing View Controller in a left direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096092/iphone-pushing-view-controller-in-a-left-direction)