# Switching View within a ViewController

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

I am building an app that requires me to switch amongst 5 views and all of them are in a single view controller class. I am able to switch them using `addSubview` and `removeFromSuperview` methods, but the problem is that I want to animate it with the current view moves out to left and the next view comes in from right.

I tried using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096092/iphone-pushing-view-controller-in-a-left-direction) but was not able to get the desired result.

Any form of help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The 5 views are fullscreen ? You want to add a transition and adding the next view like pushViewController?

Comment: yeah something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xOffSet, yoffSet);
    myView.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope this Helps....

Comment: thanks for the reply.... it worked for the first time..... bu when i get back to the parent view and again try to re-animate the whole thing nothing happens. The button that triggers the event is a cell of UITableView.... PLease suggest me the way out.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following to animate views:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f animations: 
^{
  // and of course you can edit the duration according to your need 
  // Change Alpha value of the view or set it to hidden    
  // you can also change the frame; which will make the view change it position with animation to the new provided frame. 
}
completion: ^(BOOL finished)
{
 // Your Code here; if you want to add other animation on the end of the proccess.
}

};
```