# iOS views animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to create an animation for switching views on iOS devices.
I have create an application with three views and I have some navigation buttons.
The way I use to switch views is this:

```
-(IBAction) loadThirdView:(id)sender {
[self clearView];
 self.thirdViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 208, 160, 208);
[self.view insertSubview:thirdViewController.view atIndex:0];
}
```

As you can see this is the action that takes place once I press the button. What I would like is the new view to appear in an animated way. 
Specifically I want it to start from the left hand side of the screen and slide to the right. I do not want it just to appear.

Is this possible? how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Oh no! Ah, no! Please do not display UIViewControllers this way.

Present your UIViewController this way:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.thirdViewController animated:YES]
```

Before presenting it, you can change the modalTransitionStyle property of the view controller to suit your needs.

If using a UINavigationController, use instead:

```
[yourNavController pushModalViewController:self.thirdViewController animated:YES]
```

This is a nice little article (if not a little too harsh): [Abusing UIViewControllers](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/)

To animate it the way you specifically would like (as the UINavigationController style is sliding in from the right), you might want to use something like what is proposed in this SO question: [iPhone Pushing View Controller in a left direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096092/iphone-pushing-view-controller-in-a-left-direction)

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
[UIView transitionFromView:currView toView:nextView duration:0.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
```

if you want different type of animation. There're lots AnimationsOptions you can choose, just set the `options:`.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Code :**

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
yourImageVieew.alpha=0.9;//insert here what you want

[UIView commitAnimations];
```