# How can I load a view from left side?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

This function load a view from right side. How can I Load a view from left side?

Comment: Try this link



 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096092/iphone-pushing-view-controller-in-a-left-direction/1096115#1096115

Comment: for your kind attention, actually you are trying to push a new view controller, not a UIView.

Comment: its ok dude, but, the fact is, if you are trying to add a new UIView you can do it easily using UIView with Animation, but if you are navigating to a New UIViewController you cannot do it in the below suggested ways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here it is

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:elementController animated:NO];
[animation setDuration:0.45];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];
[[elementController.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

For this you have to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Answer (score 3):

don't think there is a readymade way to do that. You will have to animate the view yourself using `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` or `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` (or any other animation methods) and change frames of your view accordingly so that it animates from the right side.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

if you already been pushed to a viewController you can use this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: im talking about a case as i described up